# Feed URL detector for an URL

Tags: url, service, rss, atom-feed

I'm looking for a code or service that can detect feed URL(RSS or Atom) of a website automatically.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For code, try the [feedfinder](http://www.aaronsw.com/2002/feedfinder/).

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Google Feed API](https://developers.google.com/feed/), particularly the lookup service which does exactly what you want (example below):

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/lookup?v=1.0&q=http://googleblog.blogspot.com/